# Create a large zip assembly with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, maven, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm having a problem with creating a larger zip assembly (uncompressed takes over 3GB) using maven-assembly-plugin. The problem occurs when building the output zip file (compressed less than 1GB). Running maven with option `-e` gives me a more detailed info:

```
[INFO] Building zip: xxx/HG19-UCSC-dist.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12:40.199s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 02 11:08:44 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/723M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-assembly) on project HG19: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single failed: invalid entry size -> [Help 1]
...
...
...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single failed: invalid entry size
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid entry size
    at java.util.zip.ZipEntry.setSize(ZipEntry.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:316)
```

Looking around I found that the issue comes from missing support for Zip64 in my JDK/JRE (https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/zip64_support_for_4g_zipfile), which was added to OpenJDK in 2011.

However, I've updated my JDK to the newest one provided by Oracle:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 03:15:32+0100)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.1.0
Java version: 1.7.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: ISO-8859-1
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

and it reports the same issue, again. Does the newest Oracle JDK have no support for Zip64 or it's something else?

I guess, I could try building OpenJDK b147 from sources but would like to avoid that unless inevitable.

Comment: Please use an up-to-date version of the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) which is currently release 2.4.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that. Unfortunately, it doesn't help much:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (make-assembly) on project HG19: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single failed: invalid entry size -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[EDIT] It's been a while but I see people reading this, so FYI the problem has been fixed since version `2.5` of the maven assembly plugin.**

I found the culprit, so reporting the issue just to save others time.

It seems that the problem lays in `org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:352)` as reported in my exception stack trace. Looking at the sources of `org.codehaus...ZipOutputStream.closeEntry` I can see:

```
entry.setSize( def.getTotalIn() );
```

and that `def` is `java.util.zip.Deflater`. However, `Deflater.getTotalIn` returns `int` not `long`. Instead the code should use `Deflater.getBytesRead()` which I'm gonna report to the developers.

Comment: Search for the latest version as of now in maven repository ( https://mvnrepository.com/ )

Comment: @Jacek, I have the same error but I don't know how to update the maven assembly plugin version. Can you help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue.
A very big (3GB) log file was occasionally picked up when building the project's jar, and this caused the issue.
No error after the file had been deleted and the size of the target jar is back to under 10Mb.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see [here, (ZipEntry class)](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.java/?v=diff&id2=6-b14), this has been fixed in the JDK 1.7.

You've shown that your `mvn` run from command line shows the JDK version 1.7.

Are you trying to complete build in the same manner, I mean from command line (and not IDE, which can use another JDK for maven?)

Comment: Yes, exactly. To build the project I use command line `mvn -e install` much like `mvn -version` shown

Comment: BTW, b147 we mentioned seems to be a bit misterious to me. The latest Oracle JDK 1.7.0_u40 reports `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)` which is far behind b147 that was reported in 2011.

Comment: Could you look at `src.zip` file of your JDK installation, and check the `setSize` method of `java/util/zip/ZipEntry.java`. Does it check size without `size > 0xFFFFFFFFL` condition?

Comment: Funny, `java/util/zip/ZipEntry.java` does not check the `size > 0xFFFFFFFFL` condition. I've also grepped all the sources and it seems that string `invalid entry size` appears in this form only in `java/util/zip/ZipEntry.java`. I see two options now: either maven uses wrong JDK, despite that it `reports 1.7.0_u40`, or there's inconsistency between src.zip and the actual binaries (which I can hardly believe).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (same error in the OP) when using the `shade` plugin that was caused by not running `mvn clean` before packaging.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I got the message 'invalid entry size' while building.
I then realized I had recently added large files in src/main/resources which are not supposed to be in the build.
This is just a reminder for anyone who might be in a situation where this error 'suddenly' appears; you might be including files that should not be included.