# Invalid or corrupt jarfile using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a project which works perfectly on eclipse, but when I try to run it on terminal using jar file then I get an error. Basically, the aim is to create a fat jar with all dependencies included.

pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.scryAnalytics</groupId>
    <artifactId>NLPAnnotationController</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>NLPAnnotationController</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hadoop.version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.1</hadoop.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <hbase.version>1.0.0-cdh5.5.1</hbase.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/cloudera-repos</url>
                </repository>
                 <repository>
                        <id>maven</id>
                        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/</url>
                </repository>

        </repositories>


    <dependencies>


<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-app</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>


<artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.ac.gate</groupId>
        <artifactId>gate-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.ac.gate</groupId>
        <artifactId>gate-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2-P20140317-1600</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>${jdk.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.scryAnalytics</groupId>
        <artifactId>NLPGeneric</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>NER</groupId>
        <artifactId>NER</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>NLPAnnotationController</finalName>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.scryAnalytics.NLPAnnotationController.GateNLPJob</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>conf</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

and when I run it I get the error shown below.

```
java -jar target/NLPAnnotationController-jar-with-dependencies.jar -inputTable posts -outputTable posts -batchId 1
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile target/NLPAnnotationController-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: What happens when you do a simple `jar tv that-jar`?

Comment: *"<mainClass>com.scryAnalytics.NLPAnnotationController.GateNLPJob</mainClass>"* Is `NLPAnnotationController` a class or a Package?

Comment: `jar tv that-jar` keeps on executing. Doesn't come to stop

Comment: "<mainClass>com.scryAnalytics.NLPAnnotationController.GateNL‌​PJob</mainClass>" is a class

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, double-check to see if the JAR file is really corrupt using `jar tv <filename.jar>`.

There are a couple of common causes for corrupt JAR files:

- The file was corrupted by copying / transferring it the wrong way; e.g. using FTP in ASCII rather than BINARY mode.
- The file system filled up while you were writing the file.
- This is the ZIP64 problem.  The original ZIP file format did not support more than 4GB in size.  This was addressed by an extension to the format, but versions of Java prior to Java 7 did not support that.

  Reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/zip64_support_for_4g_zipfile
- There is a hard limit of 65535 entries in a ZIP file.  Unfortunately, some Maven plugins does not entirely understand this limit.  When you attempt to generate a JAR with too many entries, the result is a corrupt JAR file.

  References:

  - [Invalid or corrupt JAR File built by Maven shade plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021423/invalid-or-corrupt-jar-file-built-by-maven-shade-plugin)
  - [Create a large zip assembly with maven-assembly-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135298/create-a-large-zip-assembly-with-maven-assembly-plugin)

The first three explanations are unlikely in your case, for various reasons.  That leaves a Maven plugin problem.  One of the Q&As that I found said that this was fixed in version 2.5 of the maven-assembly-plugin.  But you appear to be using a later version.  So maybe this is not the problem after all.

Anyhow:

- Check that you are using a Java 7 or later JRE or JDK on your build **and** execution platforms.
- Try updating the version of the maven assembly plugin in your POM to the latest available.

Comment: Since I'm using make-assembly plugin, how to resolve the last issue?

Comment: As far as Java and assembly plugin is considered, I have tried updating the latter but the error still persists.